# Reverse with arguments '(u'd3...',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to use django reverse url in my django template (`home-page.html`):

```
{% for entry in zippedContent %}
    <li> <p style="display: inline-block;">{{ entry.0 }}</p>
        <a href="/">
            preview
        </a>
        <p style="display: inline-block;">{{ entry.1 }}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'fileDownloadPage' entry.2 %}{{ entry.2 }}">
            download
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

here my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^home-page/', views.home_page, name="homePage"),
    url(r'^preview/', views.file_preview, name="filePreview"),
    url(r'^download/(?P<hash>[\w]+/$)', views.file_download, name="fileDownloadPage"),
```

]

and in my `views.py` I have this code for `home_page` and `file_download` views:

```
@login_required
def home_page(request):
    current_group = Group.objects.get(name=request.user.username)
    return render(request, 'home-page.html', {
    'zippedContent': zip([f.file.name for f in current_group.file_set.all()],
                         [f.privacy for f in current_group.file_set.all()],
                         [f.hash for f in current_group.file_set.all()])
})


@login_required
def file_download(request, requested_file_hash):
    try:
        requested_file = File.objects.get(hash=requested_file_hash)
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s'\
                                          % smart_str(requested_file.file.name)
        response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(requested_file.file.url)
        return response
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return Http404()
```

but when I test download url (`download/something_here`) in browser I got this error:

> Reverse for 'fileDownloadPage' with arguments '(u'd3b63b8895e15a8722668bd1da752b47842d13fa',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['download/(?P[\w]+/$)']

what is wrong with below statement in `home-page.html` page:

```
<a href="{% url 'fileDownloadPage' entry.2 %}{{ entry.2 }}">
```

Comment: Did you try `{% url 'fileDownloadPage' hash=entry.2 %}`?

Comment: Why you have `{% url 'fileDownloadPage' entry.2 %}{{ entry.2 }}` ? I think it should be `{% url 'fileDownloadPage' entry.2 %}` in the href attr.

Comment: @RetoAebersold thank you. that's work. but it is strange when I undo your change everything will OK and I don't see that error again !!!! I don't know why :)

Comment: @Gocht yes. you are right. that is my mistake.

Comment: FYI, `'zippedContent': ...` is better written `[(f.file.name, f.privacy, f,hash) for f in current_group.file_set.all()]`

Comment: @Eric oh thank you. it so cleaner now :)

Answer (score 0):

Django requires a trailing slash.  So this URL:

```
url(r'^download/(?P<hash>[\w]+/$)', views.file_download, name="fileDownloadPage"),
```

Should be:

```
url(r'^download/(?P<hash>\w+)/$', views.file_download, name="fileDownloadPage"),
```

Also, there may be an issue with the `href`.  It should change from:

```
<a href="{% url 'fileDownloadPage' entry.2 %}{{ entry.2 }}">
```

To:

```
<a href="{% url 'fileDownloadPage' entry.2 %}">{{ entry.2 }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current regex `r'^download/(?P<hash>[\w]+/$)'`, the complete capturing group is defined by `r'(?P<hash>[\w]+/$)'`. The capturing group includes the trailing slash, and when reversing, the complete capturing group is replaced by your parameter. When you pass a parameter that doesn't contain the trailing slash, it is substituted in, but it doesn't match the original regex. That's why Django raises a `NoReverseMatch`.

That's why you need to move the trailing slash out of the capturing group, as suggested by Aron:

```
url(r'^download/(?P<hash>\w+)/$', views.file_download, name="fileDownloadPage"),
```